# How to debug Django Project inside Docker Compose project (Cannot retrieve debug connection: Debug mode is not supported for...)

Tags: python, django, docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose

I've installed a docker-compose project and I am running it from IntelliJ.

- docker-compose

  - django project
  - database project
  - nginx project

I achieved to run it succesfully, and I already can deploy from IntelliJ IDE.

I configured a setting for debugging with docker-compose as in the following image.

[image]

When I click the debug icon to start debugging, I am getting the following error:

```
Deploying 'Compose: docker'...
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f /home/someone/project/docker-compose.yml up -d django db nginx
pr_django_1 is up-to-date
pr_db_1 is up-to-date
pr_nginx_1 is up-to-date
'Compose: docker' has been deployed successfully.
Cannot retrieve debug connection: Debug mode is not supported for 'Docker-compose: docker'
```

I can't find what I missed to configure it, the django webpage and whole project is visualized good, I just can't start debugging.

Comment: You are trying to debug your Django application, right?
If so, you should use Django Server run configuration which will then use your Docker Compose interpreter. See PyCharm's docs https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-compose-as-a-remote-interpreter.html
It's pretty much the same in IntelliJ IDEA